# Need to store userid appending with numbers in Java

Tags: java

I have a requirement to store user ids appending with numbers like:

If user id is "stackoverflow", then first 7 letters of id "stackov" is taken and if it not there in the DataBase then it should be stored as "stackov001".

Now if another user gives similar user id as "stackoverflowed" then its user id should be stored as "stackov002" because

I tried this by using substring but i am not able to get "00". I am able to get "stackov1" "stackov2" but not "stackov001".

Can soemone please help on this.

Comment: Code is better than English.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not provide enough research effort nor any code.

Comment: @MarounMaroun who said this word ? but I agree :D

Comment: "I tried this by using substring" then show it pls and we will correct you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String produceIdMethod(String input){

       String sub = input.substring(0, 7);//sub has 1st 7 characters

      //now fire a db query as select columnnameforid from table where columnnameforid like ':sub%' order by columnnameforid asc; 
      //and set sub dynamically using setparameter. it should give list of ids in ascending order
      //get last value of the list and lets say it as strDB
      if(retrived list is null or empty)
          return sub+"001";

      String temp = strDB.substring(7, strDB.length);//get only digits in id
      Integer i = Integer.parseInt(temp);//convert it to list
      i=i+1;//increment it
      if( i < 10 ) {
            return sub+ "00" + i;//prefix 00 if its single digit value
        }
        if( i < 100) {
            return sub+ "0" + i;prefix 0 if its double digit value
        }
        return sub+ index;//otherwise return as it is  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the partial username (the first 7 characters) and the correct index, then just do something like this:

```
public String createUsername(final String partialUsername, final int index) {
    if( index < 10 ) {
        return partialUsername + "00" + index;
    }
    if( index < 100) {
        return partialUsername + "0" + index;
    }
    return partialUsername + index;
}
```

Comment: What will be the value of INDEX over here?

Comment: Whatever your sequence number is. You say you have the partial username of 7 characters, then you say you are able to calculate the index based on whether the username is in the DB or not, so this code simply combines the two with some padding.

Answer (score 0):

try this for padding:

```
String userId = "stackov";
int cnt = 1;
userId = String.format("%s%03d",userId, cnt);
System.out.println(userId); //stackov001
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple One:

```
public static String generate(String userId,int index){
  String partialUserId=userId.substring(0,7);
  String idxString=String.format("%03d", index);
  return (partialUserId+idxString);
}
```

Presumed that you pass id with length greater than 7 otherwise throws an Exception.

Comment: What will be the value of index over here?

Comment: You may maintain a counter for that